# $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ then $\sum(a_n)$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My attempt:

$0\le \sum\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}} \le  \sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$.The series $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}$ is not convergent , by using limit comparision test and using $\frac{1}{n}$. IS this ok?

Comment: That approach is OK.

Comment: You should at least add enough detail to indicate how $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$ relates to the problem. Also elaborate on "using $1/n$".

Comment: Yes, your proof works, but you should add some more details to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \sqrt{n+1} - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure, how your attempt corresponds with the original problem. Therefore, I will present my solution.

First, we will prove by induction $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {a_i} = \sqrt {n+1}$$

Base case $n = 0$:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{0} {a_i} = a_0 = \sqrt 1 - \sqrt 0 = \sqrt {0 + 1}$$

Induction step:

Assume $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {a_i} = \sqrt {n+1}$, then $$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} {a_i} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} {a_i} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+1} {a_i} = \sqrt {n+1} + {a_{n+1}} = \sqrt {n+1} + \sqrt {n+1+1} - \sqrt {n+1} = \sqrt {(n+1)+1}$$

Therefore, we can write the sum as follows.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {a_i} = \lim_{n\to\infty}{\sum_{i=0}^{n} {a_i}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} {\sqrt {n + 1}}$$

The square root under the limit grows unbounded, thus the sum diverges.